# If $M > 0$ we have $u(x, y) \le M$ on all $\mathbb C, f$ is then constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Just want to confirm if my thinking is correct with this.
Assume $f=u+iv$. is stated;
Let $|z| = 1$ (the modulus/ $M$);
We need to show that the Real part of $f \le |z| = 1$;
$v$ is $0$ on $|z| = 1$, hence it is $0$ on $|z| \le 1$;
thus by max min principles $f$ is constant in $|z| < 1$;

Am I missing anything or does this need work. I also thought about maybe using Liouville’s theorem, which one is better?

Comment: You want to show it over all of $\Bbb{C}$, so consider $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$ and then think about $|g(z)|$ and Liouville.

Comment: Ok I think I see, so because e^f(z) can never be zero but f'(z) can we know that f(z) is constant by louivelles @AnuragA